# Can we change the green detector in vuforia object scanner ?And can two objects be recognized in vuforia?and without vuforia object scanner?

Tags: android, android-studio, vuforia, object-recognition

I am trying to do vuforia object recognition ?Need to make changes like if two objects it should identify it with some entity instead of shades.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the color: setUIScanlineColor() and setUIPointColor() methods of the TargetFinder class allow you to set the RGB float values. I did not really understand the other questions, please elaborate a bit more.

Regarding two objects - yes, Vuforia supports detection of up to 2 objects in a scene.